# psql - funcion con case

Tags: postgresql

Alguien me sabe decir que hay mal en esta funcion, siempre que meto un resultado se me va al else y ya no se por donde atacar
Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca el código por favor

Comment: No me deja el editor.. dice que hay caracteres de mas

Comment: Espera voy a generar un nuevo mensage con el codigo escrito

Comment: Pega el código, pero por lo pronto, te comento que dentro de un bloque de función no se usa CASE sino `IF...ELSE IF...ELSE...END IF`

Comment: Me desdigo, ese no es el error, voy a poner la respuesta abajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto tu error está en que pones el `BETWEEN` desde la cota superior a la inferior. [Según la documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html), el escribir

```
a BETWEEN x AND y
```

Se parsea como:

```
a >= x AND a <= y
```

Y evidentemente la nota no puede ser mayor que 100 Y menor a 90. Sólo tienes que invertir los límites:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.nota_alum(nota integer) 
RETURNS text  AS
$$
DECLARE
    Sobresaliente constant char :='A';
    Notable constant char :='B';
    Bien constant char :='C';
    Suficiente constant char :='D';
    Suspendido constant char :='N';
  msg TEXT;
BEGIN

CASE 
WHEN (nota BETWEEN 90 AND 100) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Sobresaliente;
WHEN (nota BETWEEN 70 AND 89) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Notable;
WHEN (nota BETWEEN 60 AND 69) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Bien;
WHEN (nota BETWEEN 50 AND 59) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Suficiente;
WHEN (nota BETWEEN 0 AND 49) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Suspendido;
ELSE
  msg='la nota debe estar entre 0 y 100 ';
END CASE;

RETURN msg;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

En mi comentario te había puesto que debías usar `IF...ELSEIF...ELSE...END IF;`

```
IF (nota BETWEEN 90 AND 100) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Sobresaliente;
ELSIF (nota BETWEEN 70 AND 89) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Sobresaliente;
ELSIF (nota BETWEEN 60 AND 69) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Sobresaliente;
ELSIF (nota BETWEEN 50 AND 59) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Sobresaliente;
ELSEIF (nota BETWEEN 0 AND 49) THEN
  msg='el alumne te un nota '||Sobresaliente;
ELSE
  msg='la nota debe estar entre 0 y 100 ';
END IF;
```

Pero me desdigo, tu sintaxis funciona perfecto y sólo debes invertir los rangos.

Comment: Correcto, ya funciona, me habia fijado en todo menos en eso. ;) muchas gracias